# angular.forEach, Possible to use function(key) as scope enlargement?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  angular.forEach($scope.selectedPoll.questions, function(value, key) {
                   if (key) { 
   TODO

   if ($scope.selectedPoll.survey_data[i].q1 // here i have q1 
   but i want to put (key)
```

It is some how possible to extend scope with (key) ?

so it will look like this

```
if ($scope.selectedPoll.survey_data[i].(key) ?
```

My point is that for each key from questions i habe the same key in another if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$scope.selectedPoll.survey_data[i].q1`, try below:

```
$scope.selectedPoll.survey_data[i][key]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.selectedPoll.survey_data[i][key]
```

That the way to access an object property dynamically with array notation. I don't know if i understand you weel?